# NSMutableURLRequest wrapping http body in json object

Tags: ios, swift, http, nsjsonserialization, nsmutableurlrequest

Im sending the following JSON in the body of a http post request

```
{"username":"admin", "password":"admin"}
```

This is the code

```
let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(SerializationHelper.toDictionary(user), options: .PrettyPrinted
        )
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: baseUrl + "/users/login/")!)

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"


        request.HTTPBody = jsonData

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil && data != nil else {                                                          // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        }
        task.resume()


    } catch {
        print("error")
        print(error)
    }
```

when the body is received at the server is it received as

```
{ '{"password":"admin","username":"Admin"}': '' }
```

Why is the body being set as a key in another json object? Is this default behaviour or is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: In Swift Json objects are handles as dictionary. Basically dictionary is unordered one.

Comment: The order may change but the value for the particular key will not change, unless you change it. :)

Comment: This code looks ok. It's probably an issue with the server.